# Cannot find the certificate and private key for decryption

Tags: c#, .net, certificate, code-signing

I got my certificate for code signing from GlobalSign and would like to sign my assemblies in C# .NET. However, when I follow Microsoft's manual ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247123(v=vs.80).aspx ) , at the step where I should browse for my certificate and add it, i get the error : "Cannot find the certificate and private key for decryption." with no further information. Certificate is in .pfx file. I did some research on Google but found nothing useful or working for my problem.

Comment: Are you using .NET 2.0? If not, then you shouldn't be using the MSDN pages that have vs.80 in their URL.